# C# regular expression to match a word either as a whole or only have special characters as prefix or suffix

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for matching the following conditions:

```
NPT         - match
@@#NPT      -- match
@@#NPT*)    -- match
testNPT     -- not match
testNPTtest     -- not match
@@NPT##test     -- not match
.NPT.       -- match
.NPT.abc    -- not match
```

Basically, I  need to match a word (e.g. NPT) whose prefix & suffix are not either alphabet or numeric but will match if it is a single word (NPT) or having prefix or suffix or both only special characters (e.g. @#NPT#$ OR ##NPT)

I have tried the following expression but did not get the desired result

```
(?<!^[a-z])(\bSM\b)(?![a-z])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use

```
(?<![a-z])\bNPT\b(?=\W*(?!\S))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<![a-z])`
- `\bNPT\b`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right is

  - `\W*` Match optional non word characters
  - `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right
- `)` Close lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ODbtGi/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/IteBR9)

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<![a-z])\bNPT\b(?=\W*(?!\S))");
string[] strings = {"NPT", "@@#NPT", "@@#NPT*)", "testNPT", "testNPTtest", "@@NPT##test", ".NPT.", ".NPT.abc"};

foreach (String s in strings)
{
    var m = regex.Match(s);
    if (m.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", s, m.Value);
    }
}
```

Output

```
NPT --> NPT
@@#NPT --> NPT
@@#NPT*) --> NPT
.NPT. --> NPT
```

Comment: Great. Maybe `[^\w\s]` is the same like `\W` and your regex can be simplyfied to [`(?<=^\W*)\bNPT\b(?=\W*$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cW*%29%5cbNPT%5cb%28%3f%3d%5cW*%24%29&i=NPT%0d%0a%40%40%23NPT%0d%0a%40%40%23NPT*%29%0d%0atestNPT%0d%0atestNPTtest%0d%0a%40%40NPT%23%23test%0d%0a.NPT.%0d%0a.NPT.abc&o=m) and furthermore `\b` is included in `\W` so `(?<=^\W*)NPT(?=\W*$)` Should also work.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann That might also be a solution. It depends on the allowed characters. `\W` will match a space and a newline as well, that is why I have added `\s` to the negated variation.

Comment: Hi @TheFourthBird, The above solution is working in javascript but not in Asp.net . Can u please provide the asp.net version regular expression ?

Comment: Yes you're right `\W` will match for whitespaces. The given samples doesn't contain any whitespaces so that's why I didn't check for that. Your solution is more error tolerant.

Comment: @ChanchalMaji I have added some demo C# code and a demo link https://ideone.com/pSw8x9

Comment: Hi @TheFourthBird, yes it is working in .NET when I put only say "@@#NPT*) " , but if I put  "@@#NPT*) abcd xyz "  it is not matching

Comment: @ChanchalMaji Do you mean like this? `(?<=^[^\w\s]*)\bNPT\b(?=\W*\s|$)` https://regex101.com/r/8KumRz/1

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird, I am sorry I am not able clear my requirements. The regular expression should able to match all the input word (e.g NPT) in a given string.  i.e. "#@@NPT!* NPTSD  NPT NC NC NC  NANSM abcNPTxyz #$NPT@#" will match all the related NPT

Comment: @ChanchalMaji Then you might use `(?<![a-z])\bNPT\b(?=\W*\s|$)` https://regex101.com/r/Y7Kl3k/1

Comment: @ChanchalMaji I have updated the answer with a slightly modifier pattern to account for all matches.